Why the operator norm of $A$ can be computed by maximizing the quadratic form?
I am reading the operator norm of a $m\times n$ matrix $A$:
$$
\|A\|:=\max_{x\in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}}\|Ax\|_2
$$
where $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ is the unit sphere.
I am confused about why the operator norm of $A$ can be computed by maximizing the quadratic form
$$
\|A\|=\max_{x\in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}, y\in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}}Ax\cdot y?
$$

It seems that we consider the dual space? The norm of a vector $z$ can be represented as
$$
\|z\|=\max_{\|y\|=1}z\cdot y?
$$

From the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $|Ax \cdot y| \leq |Ax| \cdot |y| = |Ax|$. Now, for an $x$ that maximizes $Ax$, show that there exists a unit vector $y$ such that $Ax \cdot y = |Ax|$.

It is due to the last fact you wrote about the representation of the norm of a vector. Using that fact, the claim follows as
$\begin{align}
\|A\| &= \max_{x\in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}} \|Ax\| \\
&= \max_{x\in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}} \left( \max_{\|y\|=1} Ax \cdot y \right) \\
&= \max_{x\in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}} \max_{ y \in \mathbb{S}^{m-1} } Ax \cdot y \\
&= \max_{x\in \mathbb{S}^{n-1} , \ y\in \mathbb{S}^{m-1}} Ax \cdot y \quad \blacksquare
\end{align}$
P.S: Minor correction on dimensions. Notice that since $A$ has dimensions $m \times n$, we should have $y \in \mathbb S^{m-1}$.

Thank you! But can you add a proof of that representation of the norm of a vector? I saw that comment that since $|Ax \cdot y|\le |Ax||y|$. But how to show the existence of such $y$ so that $Ax\cdot y=|Ax|$?

you simply take $y$ to be the unit-norm vector in the same direction as $Ax$, that is, $y := \dfrac{Ax}{| Ax |}$. This choice of $y$ results in the dot product $Ax \cdot y = Ax \cdot \dfrac{Ax}{| Ax |} = \dfrac{ | Ax |^2 }{ | Ax | } = | Ax |$, and this is what we wanted to show.

Thank you! Do we need to add absolute value in max, say $\max |Ax\cdot y|$?

I mean $|A|=\max_{|x|_2=1} |Ax\cdot x|$? Why do we need to add absolute value inside $max$?

As we know that the quantity is going to be positive, it does not matter to include the absolute value or not. They lead to the same outcome.

Why that should be positive? The inner product could be negative.

The maximal value is going to be positive, that's why the two $\max$ expressions give the same value.
